# How to solve the ClassNotFoundException of android project in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I have a android project built with Eclipse. I can build the APK, but it crashed as the following logs:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(27898): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/pili/pldroid/streaming/camera/demo/CameraStreamingActivity;
E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    at com.example.rtmpdemo.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:35)
E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4757)
E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19757)
E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258)
E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
E/AndroidRuntime(27898): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.pili.pldroid.streaming.camera.demo.CameraStreamingActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.rtmpdemo-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.rtmpdemo-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    ... 11 more
E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.pili.pldroid.streaming.camera.demo.CameraStreamingActivity
E/AndroidRuntime(27898):        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(27898):        at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
E/AndroidRuntime(27898):        at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
E/AndroidRuntime(27898):        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
E/AndroidRuntime(27898):        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
E/AndroidRuntime(27898):        ... 13 more
E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pili.pldroid.streaming.camera.demo.CameraStreamingActivity
E/AndroidRuntime(27898):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(27898):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
E/AndroidRuntime(27898):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
E/AndroidRuntime(27898):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
E/AndroidRuntime(27898):        ... 12 more
E/AndroidRuntime(27898):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
W/ActivityManager(  810):   Force finishing activity com.example.rtmpdemo/.MainActivity
```

I have defined the `CameraStreamingActivity` absolutely and registered in the AndroidManifest.xml. The structure of the project like this:

```
./AndroidManifest.xml
./assets
./libs
./libs/android-support-v4.jar
./libs/armeabi-v7a
./libs/armeabi-v7a/libpldroid_ffmpegbridge.so
./libs/pldroid-camera-streaming-1.2.0.jar
./lint.xml
./proguard-project.txt
./project.properties
./src
./src/com
./src/com/example
./src/com/example/rtmpdemo
./src/com/example/rtmpdemo/MainActivity.java
./src/com/pili
./src/com/pili/pldroid
./src/com/pili/pldroid/streaming
./src/com/pili/pldroid/streaming/camera
./src/com/pili/pldroid/streaming/camera/demo
./src/com/pili/pldroid/streaming/camera/demo/AudioStreamingActivity.java
./src/com/pili/pldroid/streaming/camera/demo/CameraStreamingActivity.java
./src/com/pili/pldroid/streaming/camera/demo/StreamingBaseActivity.java
./src/com/pili/pldroid/streaming/camera/demo/TestActivity.java
```

The AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.rtmpdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.rtmpdemo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.pili.pldroid.streaming.camera.demo.CameraStreamingActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.pili.pldroid.streaming.camera.demo.AudioStreamingActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_audio_streaming" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.pili.pldroid.streaming.camera.demo.TestActivity" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**HOWEVER, it works fine after i import the project into Android Studio.**

The import-summary.txt as following:

```
ECLIPSE ANDROID PROJECT IMPORT SUMMARY
======================================

Ignored Files:
--------------
The following files were *not* copied into the new Gradle project; you
should evaluate whether these are still needed in your project and if
so manually move them:

* .DS_Store
* ic_launcher-web.png
* proguard-project.txt

Replaced Jars with Dependencies:
--------------------------------
The importer recognized the following .jar files as third party
libraries and replaced them with Gradle dependencies instead. This has
the advantage that more explicit version information is known, and the
libraries can be updated automatically. However, it is possible that
the .jar file in your project was of an older version than the
dependency we picked, which could render the project not compileable.
You can disable the jar replacement in the import wizard and try again:

android-support-v4.jar => com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0

Moved Files:
------------
Android Gradle projects use a different directory structure than ADT
Eclipse projects. Here's how the projects were restructured:

* AndroidManifest.xml => app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
* assets/ => app/src/main/assets/
* libs/armeabi-v7a/libpldroid_ffmpegbridge.so => app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libpldroid_ffmpegbridge.so
* libs/pldroid-camera-streaming-1.2.0.jar => app/libs/pldroid-camera-streaming-1.2.0.jar
* lint.xml => app/lint.xml
* res/ => app/src/main/res/
* src/ => app/src/main/java/

Next Steps:
-----------
You can now build the project. The Gradle project needs network
connectivity to download dependencies.

Bugs:
-----
If for some reason your project does not build, and you determine that
it is due to a bug or limitation of the Eclipse to Gradle importer,
please file a bug at http://b.android.com with category
Component-Tools.

(This import summary is for your information only, and can be deleted
after import once you are satisfied with the results.)
```

What did i miss?

Thanks.

Comment: did you clear/rebuilt -- and all that standard procedure?

Comment: @Darpan Yes. I have done the procedure many times.

Comment: Are you sure the jar is added to the build path. Also you should be moving on to android studio

Comment: @Raghunandan `CameraStreamingActivity` is not in the jar, so it's nothing to do with jar. I am moving on to android studio. But the question is so strange. If anyone can explain it, that will be great.

Comment: Is your activity name correct on manifest.xml? I see `com.example.rtmpdemo.MainActivity` for mainactivity and `com.pili.pldroid.streaming.camera.demo.CameraStreamingActivity` for the second one. Is the class file in correct package?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your code don't have any problem. And this is the runtime error.

I sure that root cause is coming from libs which you import by wrong way.
"./libs/pldroid-camera-streaming-1.2.0.jar" 
Try to remove this lib and import again by other way such as:

way 1: Java build path-> Libraries -> Add External JARS..

way 2: manual copy this lib directly to ".libs/" folder

Comment: Make new folder name "reflibs" like this:
./assets
./libs
./reflibs
Manual copy "pldroid-camera-streaming-1.2.0.jar" to reflibs folder.
And then go to Java build path-> Libraries -> Add External JARS..(add pldroid-camera-streaming-1.2.0.jar )
and then go to Java build path-> Order and Export: uncheck "pldroid-camera-streaming-1.2.0.jar". Clean project and build again.